# RxJava: getting "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" even after subscribing on main thread

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am using an extensing function on autocomplete textview to use debounce strategy and subscribing  on mainthread.

```
 binding.autoCompleteTextView2.addRxTextWatcher()
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
         .subscribe {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(it)) {
                        viewModel.searchTeacher(viewModel.meditationDetails?.schoolId,it)
                        binding?.etEmailOfTeacher?.visible()   //Crash at this point
                        binding?.tvEmailOfYourTeacher?.visible()
                }
       }
```

Extension Function :-

```
fun EditText.addRxTextWatcher(): Observable<String?> {
val flowable = Observable.create<String?> {
    addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            it.onNext(s?.toString())
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }
    })
}
```

I am getting crash when I trying to update the view visibility that "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views" . But I am already subscribed and observing on mainThread . What am I doing wrong here ?

Complete Log:

```
2019-09-27 11:51:06.878 9490-9575/com.example.example E/ACRA: ACRA caught a CalledFromWrongThreadException for com.example.example
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7959)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:3866)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:917)
        at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:14121)
        at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:10007)
        at in.eightfolds.utils.ExtentionFunctionsKt.visible(ExtentionFunctions.kt:345)
        at com.example.example.fragment.OnBordingCreateMeditationAdditionalDetailsFragment$setAutoCompleteTextView2$2.accept(OnBordingCreateMeditationAdditionalDetailsFragment.kt:283)
        at com.example.example.fragment.OnBordingCreateMeditationAdditionalDetailsFragment$setAutoCompleteTextView2$2.accept(OnBordingCreateMeditationAdditionalDetailsFragment.kt:38)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:59)
        at io.reactivex.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:111)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDebounceTimed$DebounceTimedObserver.emit(ObservableDebounceTimed.java:142)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDebounceTimed$DebounceEmitter.run(ObservableDebounceTimed.java:167)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

If I write visibility inside `activity?.runOnUiThread { }`   then its working fine . So why am I getting exception even though I am subscribed on mainthread ?

Comment: it looks like the code of the extension function is incomplete, could you please add the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `debounce` operator will subscribe on the computation scheduler. Reorder your function like this:

```
binding.autoCompleteTextView2.addRxTextWatcher() <-- text watch is on the main thread
         .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) <-- debounced throw the result on Computation Scheduler
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) <-- ObserveOn throw the result on MainThread
         .subscribe {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(it)) {
                        viewModel.searchTeacher(viewModel.meditationDetails?.schoolId,it)
                        binding?.etEmailOfTeacher?.visible()   //Crash at this point
                        binding?.tvEmailOfYourTeacher?.visible()
                }
       }
```

Ref: [RxJava Debounce doc](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html)

> debounce(long, TimeUnit) is by default on the computation Scheduler

Bonus: you can use the operator `doOnNext` after each operation and log which thread is used with `Thread.currentThread().getName()`

ex:

```
...
.debounce(...)
.doOnNext{ Log.d(TAG, "Debounce on: " +  Thread.currentThread().getName()) } <-- This will show RxComputationScheduler-N
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.doOnNext{ Log.d(TAG, "Debounce on: " +  Thread.currentThread().getName()) } <-- This will show main
...
```

Comment: It looks like you just reordered the `subscribeOn` operator, that won't make any difference. According to the [docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html): `As shown in this illustration, the SubscribeOn operator designates which thread the Observable will begin operating on, no matter at what point in the chain of operators that operator is called. ObserveOn, on the other hand, affects the thread that the Observable will use below where that operator appears.`

Comment: @Gustavo Shame on me ^^

Answer (score 1):

@xiaomi's is correct regarding the `debounce` operating on the computation Scheduler by default, but in order to fix your issue, you have to switch back to main thread using `observeOn` operator after the `debounce`:

```
binding.autoCompleteTextView2.addRxTextWatcher()
         .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // debounce will operate on computation scheduler
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // change all the operators below to operate on main thread
         .subscribe {
                    // code here will be executed on main thread
                }
       }
```

From the [docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html):

> ObserveOn, affects the thread that the Observable will use below where that operator appears.